# Распознание Flash на C#

Tags: c#

Есть просто flash на котором что-то написано, как распознать что там?

Answer (score 1):

1. Есть библиотеки распознавания текста, но они ограничены
2. Для получения картинки нужны координаты флеш
3. Есть метод, который копирует определенную область экрана в Bitmap
4. Есть специальные библиотеки, которые захватывают и звук
5. Из картинок можно записать видео, но это не рационально не только из-за размера, но и из-за качества также
6. ADOBE Flash - комплексная система, это тебе не doc и не xls, ее ты не сможешь прочесть, только проиграть
7. Уточните для себя, что значит "ЧТО ТАМ?" и в каких целях.
8. Совет: в этом случае лучше сотрудничать с источником Flash